# Saving data in Firebase using delimiter in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, java-7, delimiter

I am trying to save data in my firebase such that it appear like this:
[image: Output in firebase]

I know that the way to input it manually in firebase is ["marie", "femmehacks"]
But how to I input it from android using delimiter..Note that I need to use Java 7 and String.join is not the solution in android.

Here are my codes:

```
 StringBuilder newstring = new StringBuilder();
    for (String movie: movies){
        newstring.append(movie);
        newstring.append(",");
    }

    String all = newstring.toString();
    all = all.substring(0, all.length() - ",".length());
```

The output as per this code is now:

```
["marie,femmehacks"]
```

but I want it to appear like

```
["marie", "femmehacks"]
```

such that it is saved in firebase as per the image above. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should push data  as `ArrayList<String>`

```
ArrayList<String> movies = <enter code to get list>
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(“yourChild”).setValue(movies);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function `TextUtils.join(CharSequence delimiter, Iterable tokens)`.

I got this from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils#join(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable)

```
android.text.TextUtils
public static String join(@NonNull CharSequence delimiter,
                          @NonNull Iterable tokens)
External annotations available: 
Parameter delimiter: @android.support.annotation.NonNull
Parameter tokens: @android.support.annotation.NonNull
```

You may try like this. ***its works for me.***

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
private String membersName = "";

for (UserInfo userInfo : userInfoList) {
    stringList.add(userInfo.getUsername());
}

membersName = TextUtils.join(", ", stringList);
```

***you can save like :***

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(“ChildName”).setValue(membersName);
```